# There are any default triggers(hooks) for updates with WebServices?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I did some updates (eg: product quantity) from a 3-rd party with PS via `PS_WS`.
 My issue is that I cannot trigger the event using any default hooks.

Eg: `hookActionUpdateQuantity` : working fine only when updates come directly from PS:`front#sales`*or*`backOffice#increase_stock`)

Assume that `PS_WS` can be altered, but this is the only option ?

Shouldn't PS have a trigger(hook) for WS ?

(at least from my point of view is good to know from where the changes are comming)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

actionObject*class_name*AddBefore

actionObject*class_name*AddAfter

actionObject*class_name*UpdateBefore

actionObject*class_name*UpdateAfter

actionObject*class_name*DeleteBefore

actionObject*class_name*DeleteAfter

For quantity change it will be actionObjectStockAvailableAddAfter and actionObjectStockAvailableUpdateAfter

Comment: Not sure if use any of the pattern described `actionObjectclass_name` ... have to recheck !